# Show $4x^3 + y^3 = 792,864,313,578,917,724,246$ has no solution for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, law-of-large-numbers

I think it involves something about looking at the last digits of the number and/or modular arithmetic but I don't remember how to do this. Help?

Comment: Try reducing the equation modulo some number m.Try looking at the coefficients and see what the most suitable value of m might be.

Comment: Note that a number is divisible by 4 exactly when the number modulo 100 is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume there is such a solution $(x,y)$. 
Since $4x^3$ and the right hands side are even, we conclude that $y$ is even. Then the left hand side is a multiple of $4$, but the right hand side is not - contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

You want the sum to be even. That means that $y$ must be even. So say $y = 2m$, then
$$
4x^3 + y^3 = 4x^3 + 8m^3 = 4(x^3 + 2m^3).
$$
(It is not hard to see that $2\cdot 39643215678945886212\color{red}3 = 792864313578917724246$)

Comment: (Read my comment above).